# tic tac toe - no match for operator* error

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, operators

I'm trying to write a tic tac toe game in C++, but whenever I run it I get an error message saying:

```
TicTacToe.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void copy_array(T*, T*) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’:
TicTacToe.cpp:115:25:   required from here
TicTacToe.cpp:93:3: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘**(new_arr + ((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’
```

It points to this function:

```
86    template<class T>
87    void copy_array(T old_arr[], T *new_arr)
88    {
89      int size = sizeof(old_arr)/sizeof(old_arr[0]);
90      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
91      {
92          *new_arr[i] = old_arr[i];
93      }
94    }
```

An this piece of code:

```
114    string copy[9];
115    copy_array(board, copy);
```

Could anyone please explain to me what's causing the error and how to solve it?

Comment: In terms of programming I fail to see what this problem has to do with the game of tic-tac-toe.

Comment: Two things. (a) Who told you to do `int size = sizeof(old_arr)/sizeof(old_arr[0]);` here? (b) Did you shoot them in the face for me yet?

Comment: Don't use that silly sizeof trick. It is terrible because it gives you the idea that it works, and then doesn't. Use the size function from here: https://gist.github.com/3959946, or stop using arrays altogether (superior alternatives include `std::vector` or `std::array` depending on usage). Don't take `[]` arguments. Those are not arrays, but actually pointers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Your `size` function template instantiations should take `const`, please. And, yes, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is quite strange, it appears to be printing out a transformed version of your code, but I'm pretty sure it's referring to this line:

```
*new_arr[i] = old_arr[i];
```

Remove the `*` and you should be fine.

Although of course it won't function as you expect. Your argument `T old_arr[]` is going to act exactly like `T *old_arr`. Notably, `sizeof()`, which you're relying on to give you the full size of the array, won't.

You could use the following template to get around this:

```
template<class T, int N>
void copy_array(T (&old_arr)[N], T *new_arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        new_arr[i] = old_arr[i];
    }
}
```

Or, if you can use C++11, you could switch to `std::array<>`, which knows its size.

Comment: This may fix that error, but it won't be fine (the size calculation is wrong).

Comment: I don't see what's all that strange about it. It's showing the line after `a[b]` is resolved into its true meaning and with types made explicit. GCC does that for, well, all of its diagnostics.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yes, but a) the error was what the post is about, not the game logic, and b) I was still adding information.

Comment: `You could use the following template to get around` Nope, you're still accepting an array by value, which invokes decay.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: It's strange because it's now much harder to identify the line from the error message.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: The size of the array is now part of the template.

Comment: @Kevin: I don't see what's hard about identifying the line from the error message when the error message tells you the line number.

Comment: @KevinBallard: Yet until you accept the array by _reference_, the array name still decays into a pointer. Try it.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel: Oh good catch, I did miss the reference. I'll fix that.

Comment: Oh wow, where did this come from. I guess SO is really glitching out today.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
*new_arr[i] = old_arr[i];
```

for this:

```
new_arr[i] = old_arr[i];
```

when you use the brackets c++ internally dereference the pointer.

Comment: rember that the arrays are pointers, if you want to use  the * you should put *(new_arr+i)= old_arr[i]

Comment: a pointer stores a memory direction and a variable that stores an "array" it stores the direction of the first element of the arrayy  so when i said arrays are pointers what i mean is that "old_arr" is a pointer to an array

Answer (score 0):

This does a safer variation of what you want:

```
template<typename T, size_t size>
void copy_array(T (&old_arr)[size], T (&new_arr)[size])
{
    std::copy(&old_arr[0], &old_arr[0] + size, &new_arr[0]);
}
```

It enforces that the size of the destination is the same as the size of the source. If you end up wanting to override that, you really should reconsider your design.